# jQuery is swallowing my touch events on iOS Safari

Tags: jquery, ios, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootbox

I have a web application built on the bootstrap framework that is loading a bootbox.js modal populated by a form that is loaded via ajax on top of a google map.

To handle touch devices we have decided to specifically support iOS touch, otherwise traditional desktop keyboard / mouse input - it fits our intended target audience.

I am using the tocca library to add tap event support (touchstart / touchend are not natural replicas of the click event in a touch environment).
http://gianlucaguarini.com/Tocca.js/

I am then using the following method to catch touch events and convert them to tap events:

```
//if touch is supported, switch click events to touchStart events
    supportTouch: function(){
        console.warn("SUPPORTING TOUCH DEVICE EVENTS");
        if(plenty_admin.iOS){
            //save current implementation of on as "_on"
            $.fn.extend({ _on: (function(){ return $.fn.on; })() });
            $.fn.extend({
                on: (function(){
                    //var isTouchSupported = 'ontouchstart' in window || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch;
                    return function( types, selector, data, fn, one ) {
                        //do not modify the event type of form elements
                        if( 
                            plenty_admin.iOS
                        ){
                            if(
                                $(this).is("input")
                                || $(this).is("select")
                                || $(this).is("textarea")
                            ){
                                return this._on( types, selector, data, fn);
                            }
                        }

                        if (typeof types === 'string' && !(types.match(/touch/gi))) types = types.replace(/click/gi, 'tap');
                        return this._on( types, selector, data, fn);
                    };
                }())
            });
        }else{
            document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){
                //alert("Touch support in this application is only available on iOS Devices. Please use a keyboard and mouse or switch to an iPad.");
                bootbox.dialog({
                    title: "Touch and pointer input only supported on iOS",
                    message: "You seem to be using an input device other than a mouse on a non-iOS device.<br><br>This is not supported by Plenty at this time.<br><br>Please use a keyboard and mouse or sign in to Plenty on your iPad.",
                    className: "info",
                    buttons: {
                            danger: {
                              label: "OK",
                              className: "btn-info",
                              callback: plenty_admin.HELPER.hideLoadingOverlay
                            }
                    },
                    callback:plenty_admin.HELPER.hideLoadingOverlay,
                    onEscape:plenty_admin.HELPER.hideLoadingOverlay
                })
                .init(plenty_admin.HELPER.add_icons_to_bootbox_btns);
            });
        }
    }
```

This solution works fine across the entire app on iOS Safari, except one place I have found, which is our map page.

I am using a custom map control to start a flow for adding polygons to the map. The initial step is to load a set of boundaries, the user chooses one, and chooses to make a field from it. This is handled in a google maps info window and triggers my bootbox modal.

When the modal opens, the form fields do not work - no keyboard is shown, and the select lists do not open.

Adding breakpoints to the event handlers associated with the form elements takes me to one jQuery method:

```
r.event = {
    global: {},
    add: function(a, b, c, d, e) {
        var f,
            g,
            h,
            i,
            j,
            k,
            l,
            m,
            n,
            o,
            p,
            q = V.get(a);
        if (q) {
            c.handler && (f = c, c = f.handler, e = f.selector), e && r.find.matchesSelector(qa, e), c.guid || (c.guid = r.guid++), (i = q.events) || (i = q.events = {}), (g = q.handle) || (g = q.handle = function(b) {
                return "undefined" != typeof r && r.event.triggered !== b.type ? r.event.dispatch.apply(a, arguments) : void 0
            }), b = (b || "").match(K) || [""], j = b.length;
            while (j--)
                h = ta.exec(b[j]) || [], n = p = h[1], o = (h[2] || "").split(".").sort(), n && (l = r.event.special[n] || {}, n = (e ? l.delegateType : l.bindType) || n, l = r.event.special[n] || {}, k = r.extend({
                    type: n,
                    origType: p,
                    data: d,
                    handler: c,
                    guid: c.guid,
                    selector: e,
                    needsContext: e && r.expr.match.needsContext.test(e),
                    namespace: o.join(".")
                }, f), (m = i[n]) || (m = i[n] = [], m.delegateCount = 0, l.setup && l.setup.call(a, d, o, g) !== !1 || a.addEventListener && a.addEventListener(n, g)), l.add && (l.add.call(a, k), k.handler.guid || (k.handler.guid = c.guid)), e ? m.splice(m.delegateCount++, 0, k) : m.push(k), r.event.global[n] = !0)
        }
    },
```

If I set a breakpoint on the following line:
return "undefined" != typeof r && r.event.triggered !== b.type ? r.event.dispatch.apply(a, arguments) : void 0

The app pauses, and the form works as expected. Allowing this method to run seems to prevent or remove the form interaction.

Controls in the footer of the bootbox modal work as expected. The "New Farm" link also works as expected.

What is more, once I close the bootbox modal, other map controls seem to loose their click > tap event handler.

I have tried to par down the page to recreate the issue but with a simplified but accurate reproduction of the problem I am unable to reproduce the issue - my isolated demo works on iPad and is available here:
http://admin.plenty.rdthree.com/map-modal-test.html

I am using the latest iOS on an iPad Air.

On arrangement I can take you through to the issue on the running application if you could help me to identify the cause.

Many thanks indeed for your help on a complex and frustrating issue.

If you feel more information is required I will do my best to provide.

Comment: I see this question was viewed 15 times without any response or input. Can I ask if there is anything I can add, clarify, try or explain to help you help me? Many thanks.

Comment: Still no takers or suggestions of how I might better debug or approach an issue such as this?

Comment: Doubt it's the issue, but you don't really need that .init() call on your dialog; you can add HTML to your button labels directly, as shown in [this example](http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html#also-applies-to-alert-prompt-custom%0A%0Awith-icon-and-button-text). I only mention it because there is a problem with init that I've been trying to isolate, but haven't been able to fix yet.

Comment: Thanks Tieson - the .init() method sets up the behaviour of the form components once they have been added to the modal. In the full app this functionality is a separate method - I have tried disabling to no effect on iOS - it just stops the form populating. Before submitting this ticket I commented out all code associated with the popup once it was opened but can't isolate the issue.

Only way I can make the form behave is putting a breakpoint on the jquery line:
    return "undefined" != typeof r && r.event.triggered !== b.type ? r.event.dispatch.apply(a, arguments) : void 0

Comment: Any console output on iOS related to the malfunction?

Comment: Nothing relevant mystrdat I'm afraid, no errors logged, and until opening the popup the app and this specific page work as expected. It is a browser based SAS web app I am trying to ensure works smoothly on iOS Safari iPad, not an iOS WebApp specifically. Until reaching the line I described above in jQuery the form works. Thinking of hosting this version of jQuery locally and hacking this specific method as a last chance work around.

Comment: so I tracked it down to this in non-minified jQuery:
    if ( !( eventHandle = elemData.handle ) ) {
   eventHandle = elemData.handle = function( e ) {

    // Discard the second event of a jQuery.event.trigger() and
    // when an event is called after a page has unloaded
    return typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type ?
     jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( elem, arguments ) : undefined;
   };
  }
    
I'm going with a custom version of jQuery with a hack in it for now to see if I can work around this issue - any input on a clean workaround very welcome